# adjusting view after hiding navigation bar

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an app that has both navigationbar and toolbar on display with various buttons...

I have an imageview that will act as a help overlay (like you see in many apps these days) that is semi transparent with arrows pointing to the buttons on the bars plus actual view content.

First attempt displays the imageview in the view area but leaving the bars in place...not good!

So next attempt I have included the bars as part of the imageview and add this to take up the entire screen, so far so good. I then hide the bars but oh no.....the view moves up 44 pixels (as expected)

Problem is no matter what I do I cannot get the view to move down the 44 pixels?

So the imageview displays the bars giving the illusion the overlay (imageview) is on top, but the view in between is out of whack!

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 750, 1024)];

iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];

UIWindow *window = self.view.window;

[window addSubview:iv];
```